# How to update single field whith sending id

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to set `status = 1` with using the record **id**. But this not work.

I send the id from index page (bellow image).

[image]

```
public function actionConfirm($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        $model->status = 1;
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->render('index');
        } else {
            die('not work'); //this clause works 
        }
    }
```

How can I do this.

Comment: Use AJAX to send update request, perform it and send result back to this view.

Comment: I don't know about ajax much, could you please show me how do I have to do it?

Comment: Not really but there are plenty of examples all over the web, just google it.

Comment: You've got some validation problems cause $model->save() return false

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems in your validation.

The causes can be two

1. `$model = $this->findModel($id)` can't find the record you're looking for by the id
2. Somehow you save in your db records are incomplete and can't be saved in the db.

Solutions:

First, since you're doing an update, i suggest you to use  `$model->update()` [method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#update()-detail)

But in both case (update() or save()) if you want to force the update of the field you should pass false to $runValidation parameter

```
public function actionConfirm($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        $model->status = 1;
        if ($model->update(false)) {
            return $this->render('index'); // now this works
        } else {
            die('not work');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your button in action column is named check 
In your action column you could invoke

```
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{delete}{update}{viwq}{check}',               
            'buttons' => [
                'check' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>', $url, [
                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Confirm'),
                    ]);
                }
             ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action === 'check') {
                    $url = Url::to(['/your-controller/confirm', 'id' =>$model->id]);
                return $url;
                }
            }
        ]            
    ],
```